# videos from non-linux partition don't play

Tags: 22.04, video, snap, smplayer

I installed linux dual boot with windows, now I can't play any videos from another mounted partition.

I should also mention that only videos have this problem and I can open pictures, documents, music, ... with no problem. Also the problem is not video codecs, If I copy and paste video in linux partition it playes flawlessly.

I tried opening with smPlayer and media player and no success.SmPlayer error log:
`MPV has finished unexpectedly. Exit code: 2`

```
/snap/smplayer/76/usr/bin/mpv --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-ipc-server=/tmp/smplayer-mpv-96c1 --msg-level=ffmpeg/demuxer=error --video-rotate=no --no-config --no-fs --hwdec=no --sub-auto=fuzzy --no-input-default-bindings --input-vo-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=88080420 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-level=1 --osd-scale=1 --osd-bar-align-y=0.6 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --sub-ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1 --sub-font=Arial --sub-color=#ffffffff --sub-shadow-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-size=0.75 --sub-shadow-offset=2.5 --sub-font-size=50 --sub-bold=no --sub-italic=no --sub-margin-y=8 --sub-margin-x=20 --sub-codepage=ISO-8859-1 --sub-pos=100 --volume=55 --cache=auto --screenshot-template=cap_%F_%p_%02n --screenshot-format=jpg --screenshot-directory=/home/nymeria/Pictures/smplayer_screenshots --audio-pitch-correction=yes --volume-max=110 --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:}
INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width}
INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height}
INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-params/aspect}
INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=container-fps:${=fps}}
INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format}
INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec}
INFO_DEMUX_ROTATION=${=track-list/0/demux-rotation}
INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name}
INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate}
INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count}
INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}}
INFO_DEMUXER=${=current-demuxer:${=demuxer}}
INFO_SEEKABLE=${=seekable}
INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles}
INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters}
INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count}
METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:}
METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:}
METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:}
METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:}
METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:}
METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:}
METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:}
INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}
INFO_STREAM_PATH=${stream-path}
 --audio-client-name=SMPlayer --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} VB: ${=video-bitrate:0} AB: ${=audio-bitrate:0} /media/nymeria/New Volume/Downloads/Attack.on.Titan.S04E30.720p.10bit.WEB-DL.x265.SoftSub.DigiMoviez.mkv

[file] Cannot open file '/media/nymeria/New Volume/Downloads/Attack.on.Titan.S04E30.720p.10bit.WEB-DL.x265.SoftSub.DigiMoviez.mkv': Permission denied
Failed to open /media/nymeria/New Volume/Downloads/Attack.on.Titan.S04E30.720p.10bit.WEB-DL.x265.SoftSub.DigiMoviez.mkv.
Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

I tried mounting the partition with sudo and It did not fix the problem.

I read somewhere that the problem could be because partition format is not ext4, but I had linux manjaro before this and had no problem palying videos from the same partition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The SMPlayer snap does not seem to have permissions to access the partition. This seems to be a snap issue. Installing the APT version should fix it.

```
sudo snap remove smplayer
sudo apt install smplayer
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: Not my DV, but does apt actually install the non-snap version? It often installs the snap anyway

Comment: AFAIK, apt installs the snap version for a few apps like Firefox, Chromium and Telegram. For most apps, it does install the debian package.

Comment: It's definitely the case for firefox, even going so far as to remove the properly installed version (and its ppa) and replace it with a snap when going from 20.04 to 22.04, at which point lots of things didn't work.  Another example is **pdftk**, which is what made me detest snaps so much in the first place.  Not only does it not read/write `/tmp`, it fails silently - probably the worst anti-user behaviour I've seen in the *nix world.  Knowing that some common binaries are installed as snaps against the user's wishes, I'd want solid, tested confirmation that it does what it's told for smplayer

Comment: At least on 20.04 you're right and apt works properly

Comment: Compare https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=smplayer and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox. You will see that the version number of firefox has snap. SMPlayer does not.

Comment: I have asked a question regarding this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494899/where-can-i-find-the-list-of-dummy-apt-packages-which-actually-install-snap

Answer (score 14):

This is most likely due to the default security policy for [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/) applications regarding connecting to [the removable-media interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface) which is usually **not** granted by default ... You can inspect that for snap installed `smplayer` like so:

```
$ snap connections smplayer
Interface               Plug                             Slot                     Notes
alsa                    smplayer:alsa                    -                        -
audio-playback          smplayer:audio-playback          :audio-playback          -
desktop                 smplayer:desktop                 :desktop                 -
desktop-legacy          smplayer:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy          -
dvb                     smplayer:dvb                     -                        -
home                    smplayer:home                    :home                    -
jack1                   smplayer:jack1                   -                        -
mount-observe           smplayer:mount-observe           -                        -
mpris                   -                                smplayer:mpris           -
network                 smplayer:network                 :network                 -
network-bind            smplayer:network-bind            :network-bind            -
network-control         smplayer:network-control         -                        -
network-manager         smplayer:network-manager         -                        -
opengl                  smplayer:opengl                  :opengl                  -
optical-drive           smplayer:optical-drive           :optical-drive           -
pulseaudio              smplayer:pulseaudio              -                        -
removable-media         smplayer:removable-media         -                        -
screen-inhibit-control  smplayer:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control  -
unity7                  smplayer:unity7                  :unity7                  -
wayland                 smplayer:wayland                 :wayland                 -
x11                     smplayer:x11                     :x11                     -
```

... and can be enabled with:

```
sudo snap connect smplayer:removable-media
```

... so it will report as such:

```
$ snap connections smplayer
Interface               Plug                             Slot                     Notes
alsa                    smplayer:alsa                    -                        -
audio-playback          smplayer:audio-playback          :audio-playback          -
desktop                 smplayer:desktop                 :desktop                 -
desktop-legacy          smplayer:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy          -
dvb                     smplayer:dvb                     -                        -
home                    smplayer:home                    :home                    -
jack1                   smplayer:jack1                   -                        -
mount-observe           smplayer:mount-observe           -                        -
mpris                   -                                smplayer:mpris           -
network                 smplayer:network                 :network                 -
network-bind            smplayer:network-bind            :network-bind            -
network-control         smplayer:network-control         -                        -
network-manager         smplayer:network-manager         -                        -
opengl                  smplayer:opengl                  :opengl                  -
optical-drive           smplayer:optical-drive           :optical-drive           -
pulseaudio              smplayer:pulseaudio              -                        -
removable-media         smplayer:removable-media         :removable-media         manual
screen-inhibit-control  smplayer:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control  -
unity7                  smplayer:unity7                  :unity7                  -
wayland                 smplayer:wayland                 :wayland                 -
x11                     smplayer:x11                     :x11                     -
```

... and this can be disabled anytime with:

```
sudo snap disconnect smplayer:removable-media
```

**Notice** this can also be done from the UI of the `snap-store` AKA Software app like this:

[image]