# Where can I find the list of dummy apt packages which actually install snap?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, snap

Does Ubuntu publish a list of packages which are the snap package in pulled in when one installs a dummy APT package?

I know that Chromium (20.04+) and Firefox (22.04+) are among them. Is there anything else?

Some users are [already under the impression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494599/videos-from-non-linux-partition-dont-play?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2619172_1494600) that "it often installs the snap anyway", so having a definitive list will be helpful.

Comment: Published list? Never seen one. Suggest starting such a list in an answer. Folks can edit to add. The list will change over time. Example: 24.10 is expected to add CUPS.

Comment: I'm not aware that a list like this exists, at least not in a public avaible place. Possible options how to determine:
1. Parse the description of each package for the word "snap" - not really reliable, as mentioning here the DEB installs a snap isn't enforce.
2. Parse the dependencies of each package and check whether the package requires snapd. Should be kind of reliable.
3. Parse the commands execute while installing the DEB and check for `snap install ...`. Probably most reliable, but most coding work.