# How can I create an LVM Partion /var/tmp in Ubuntu Server 22.04, without crashing the system?

Tags: 22.04, lvm

To make it clear, I managed LVM and partitioning 1000+ times on RHEL and Debian derivatives,
but Ubuntu Server 22.04 seems to have a serious bug!

**What is:**

If I install a fresh VM, I can create every partitioning schema I want with LVM *except* `/var/tmp/`. Then the installer will crash.

If I try to manage /var/tmp on a running system, Ubuntu won't boot. I use a systemcrescue System to manage it in safe mode.

Still it crashes without giving me any info about the cause.

Has anybody had the same issue and can give me a hint how to fix it?
Again, it is not a problem on a RHEL, ROCKY, Alma etc. System. Debian-12 has also no problem at all!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site where answers are given by other users like you. Bugs are off topic here. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) and report the bug. Before reporting you may want to search and check if it has been reported already. If already reported, add yourself as affected by the bug.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do, exactly? `/tmp` on Ubuntu Server isn't on your drive, it's a ramdisk. What exactly are you trying to do here? Mount a partition onto `/tmp/var`? Partition the already mounted filesystem(?)? PLease [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon `mount|grep /tmp` shows nothing on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 server VM. A ramdisk may be the default for other Unix&Linux, but I've never seen it like this on Ubuntu

Comment: Dammit, this is the second time I get this wrong. Are you sure though, @DanielT?  I have several Ubuntu Server installs at work and all of them have a tmpfs system mounted at `/tmp` but that might be something our sysadmins set up. However, someone else [recently told me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503475/file-removal-on-power-off/1503508#comment2637100_1503508) this is the default for Server installs. Maybe it is different on VMs?